# ListView is not updating

Tags: android

So i have a listview which shows every audio file on my device. It runs good but it doesnt update after first use, If i add copy new audio file to my device it will not show in listview. It shows only if I reinstall the application

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
     SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
               boolean samples = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox", false);
               if (samples==false) 
               musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
               else{
                   musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);}
               count = musiccursor.getCount();
               musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
               musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext(), count, null));
               musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
```

UPDATE
after some research i saw that i need to update MediaStore, I know I can scan for one file with `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("FILENAME"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));` but how can i do that for all audio files?

Comment: add a reload button/mechanism

Answer (score 1):

You have to notify Listview that count value got changed. So create a method in MusicAdapter to set new content list in Listview.

Comment: i did some research and i saw that i need to update MediaStore?

Answer (score 0):

Notify your music adapter so it can update. Try this:

```
MusicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: There is no error, it just doesnt update the list, i think i need to update MediaStore

Answer (score 0):

Making your list adapter (MusicAdapter) extend android.widget.CursorAdapter will allow it to track changes in the underlying content provider and update the associated list view.

Also, Activity.managedQuery has been deprecated a long time ago, please use [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) for associating cursors with activity lifecycle instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to recheck for all the audio files on your computer. On this button click, use the same procedure as you are using now to detect audio files. After detecting all the files, update the adapter of the listView.